# Android API IsConnected returning TRUE after Signing Out

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services, monogame, google-play-games

I am developing a game for Android using Google Play Game Services, using Xamarin. I am doing my testing using a Genymotion Android Emulator. I have run into an issue that appears to be a bug in either Google Play or Xamarin's implementation.

If I **sign out of a Google account**, calls to the **IGoogleApiClient.IsConnected()** continue to **return true** (even though I have clearly just signed out). If I then attempt to use that API object, I will get exceptions like:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Not signed in when calling API

For example, the follow code results in the above exception if executed after signing out:

```
public void StartNewMatch()
{
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.IsConnected)
    {
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = GamesClass.TurnBasedMultiplayer.GetSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 1, true);
    StartActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
}
```

I am signing out in the Google Play Games Inbox (match picker); as shown in the images below.

Anyone run into this before? Am I missing something? Got any work-arounds?

**Note: This only occurs if signing out through Google's UI.** If I manually sign the user out, with something like `mGoogleApiClient.Disconnect()`, the issue does not occur; `mGoogleApiClient.IsConnected()` now returns false (as expected).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to keep signed-in state synced up you MUST implement onActivityResult properly.

This should look something as follows:

NOTE: this is java code, I am not sure how this will look exactly using Xamarin, but hopefully you should be able to figure it out :)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {

    // check for "inconsistent state"
    if ( responseCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED && requestCode == <your_request_code_here> )  {  

       // force a disconnect to sync up state, ensuring that mClient reports "not connected"
       mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

NOTE: just make sure to replace  in the code with the request code you used. You may need to check for multiple request codes too.

Comment: That worked great. A couple notes: 1) responseCode is a Result enum in Xamarin, which needs to be cast to an int and 2) I didn't bother checking the requestCode as I figured this responseCode should result in disconnecting regardless of what triggered it.

Comment: Should be fine not checking the requestCode as long as you don't launch any other activities from your app, as they might use the same response value for something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gameHelper classes from BaseGameUtils library(it is easier to use), you may modify the above code to this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED){
        // force a disconnect to sync up state, ensuring that mClient reports "not connected"
        gameHelper.getApiClient().disconnect();
    }
}
```