# Google Play game services GameHelper's isSignedIn() return true after user signs out

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-games

If user signs out from Achievements (or other) dialog isSignedIn() still returns true. Some code example:

I have this button:

```
    achievementsBtn = new TextButton("achievements", menuBtnStyle);
    achievementsBtn.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            if (MyGdxGame.actionResolver.getSignedInGPGS())
                MyGdxGame.actionResolver.getAchievementsGPGS();
            else MyGdxGame.actionResolver.loginGPGS();
        }
    });
```

where

```
@Override
public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
    startActivityForResult(
            Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper
                    .getApiClient()), 101);

}

@Override
public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
    return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
}
```

After a user clicks Sign Out here and returns to the game nex time he clicks achievements button game crashes.

[image]

with this exception:

```
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 279
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime: Process: ru.zuko.game.android, PID: 29940
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Not signed in when calling API
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService$Stub$Proxy.lm(Unknown Source)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.lm(Unknown Source)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.AchievementsImpl.getAchievementsIntent(Unknown Source)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.zuko.game.android.AndroidLauncher.getAchievementsGPGS(AndroidLauncher.java:292)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.zuko.screens.StartScreen$4.clicked(StartScreen.java:116)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:89)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:58)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:348)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:361)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:420)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1522)
10-15 19:23:56.988 29940-29989/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

What can I do to make my game work properly?

Comment: Looks like you need to signed-in state synced up you MUST implement onActivityResult properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902935/android-api-isconnected-returning-true-after-signing-out

Comment: Thanks, I already made something like this.